# How to remove click-to-call links for IE mobile browsers

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, mobile-website, meta-tags, mobile-browser

Hi 
I am able to remove click-to-call links for labels / numbers in Iphone & Blackberry by keeping the above tags in the header part.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> //for Safari
<meta http-equiv="x-rim-auto-match" content="none"> //for Blackberry
```

Like this do we have any property for Internet Explorer ( Windows Mobile Browser ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this functionality is not present in the current release of the OS and IE will parse numbers, addresses and emails automatically. As per the [public doc](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/5/93565816-AD4E-4448-B49B-457D07ABB991/Windows%20Internet%20Explorer%20Mobile%20on%20Windows%20Phone%207_FINAL_122010.pdf):

> Internet Explorer Mobile automatically
>   recognizes phone numbers, email
>   addresses, and physical addresses on
>   webpages, regardless of whether they
>   were designed as hyperlinks or not—so
>   users can make a phone call, send an
>   email, or map an address with just a
>   tap or two.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your number in <pre> tag. This will remove click-to-call links even in iPhone, without meta tags.

P.S. Tested on HTC HD7 and iPhone 4

Comment: I found that when using <pre> tags, it causes a line break, so if you had something like: "call <pre>555-5555</pre>" it would display on two lines. If you use <code> instead of <pre> then it keeps everything on one line.