# Stop windows phone 7 from automatically formatting phone numbers

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile

I'm developing a mobile web application and I have been given some pretty strict style guidelines from the designer.  In all other mobile OSes I have stopped the OS from auto creating a link from the phone number in the listing page...However I can't accomplish that in WP7.

For the others I used

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

Any ideas how to do this in WP7?

Comment: Have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976061/how-to-remove-click-to-call-links-for-ie-mobile-browsers

Comment: Have you asked the designer why they don't want the numebrs you're displaying to be easy for the user to use? It sounds like the designer has no mobile experience and isn't aware that the value on return for trying to make HTML render exactly the same on **ALL** mobile platforms is ridiculously small. If you want it to look the same everywhere then make it a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.   In fact, the phone number, fax number and address do not show up at all regardless of the CSS.  There's not much return on that.  Until a proper solution is found I have resorted to adding a space between every number/letter in the address and phone numbers and then changed the letter-spacing to -2px in CSS to tighten the spacing back up.  WP7 no longer recognizes them as an address or phone numbers and they look just as they would otherwise.